# Delete last layer and insert three Conv2D layers in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a model in Keras for classification that I trained on some dataset. Call that model "classification_model". That model is saved in "classification.h5". Model for detection is the same, except that we delete last convolutional layer, and add three `Conv2D` layers of size `(3,3)`. So, our model for detection "detection_model" should look like this:

detection_model = classification_model[: last_conv_index] + Conv2d + Conv2d + Conv2d.

How can we implement that in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, load your classification model and use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to construct your new model:

```
model = load_model("classification.h5")

last_conv_layer_output = model.layers[last_conv_index].output
conv = Conv2D(...)(last_conv_layer_output)
conv = Conv2D(...)(conv)
output = Conv2D(...)(conv)

new_model = Model(model.inputs, output)

# compile the new model and save it ...
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and got an error: TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f3f24b5f390>

Comment: @Alem Are you sure you have passed the arguments to the layers, i.e. `(conv)`?

Comment: I forgot the last one. I fixed it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: What will happen with the pretrained weights in classification.h5 now in new_model?

Comment: @Alem Those layers of `model` which are used in `new_model` as well, will be saved when you save `new_model` and will be updated it if you train `new_model`. However, obviously the weights in "classification.h5" will not change and you can load the original model whenever you want using this file.

Comment: What if I want my network to start training with those weights in the first model and new_model to start learning from those weights?

Comment: @Alem If I understand your question correctly, the answer is it is done. The weights of `model` will be used for training `new_model` and if you don't freeze the corresponding layers (i.e. `the_layer.trainable = False`), the weights will be updated as well.